# Custom icon for menu item on prime faces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have to add customized icon for menu item. please any one suggest  me?
I have set the icon using CSS class but am not getting displaying.

```
<p:submenu label="Administration" >
    <p:menuitem value="Role Master" url="/secured/role_master.xhtml?redirect=true" />
    <p:menuitem value="Role Assignment" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="User Management" url="/secured/users.xhtml?redirect=true" icon="user"/>
</p:submenu>
```

and below code represent css class

```
.user{
    background: url('resources/images/menu/users.png') no-repeat;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
.user{
    background-image: url('resources/images/menu/users.png') !important;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
      .tabmenubutton
        {
         background:url("common/images/calendar.png") no-repeat !important;
         width:20px;
         height:20px;
        }
```

xhtml:

```
      <p:menuitem value="Country" icon="tabmenubutton"/>
```